# Downloading a file using PHP saves an empty file

Tags: php

I created a download.php file in my vps server which has some images, if users request the file using this file, the file is saved to the devices. But this creates an empty file. This is the code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['file']))
{
    $filename = $_GET["file"];
    if(preg_match('/^[^.][-a-z0-9_.]+[a-z]$/i', $file)){
        $filepath = "images/" . $file;
        if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\""); 
           readfile($filepath);
        }
    }
?>
```

I have corrected the typos and removed echo still , it is the same, The file is downloaded when `download.php?file=abstract.jpg` is invoked on the server.

Comment: Typo, extra underscore: `readfile($filepath);`

Comment: How do you serve this? How do you invoke it? This question effectively lacks a [mcve], which makes it impossible to answer. I also don't see any place where a file is saved. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You don't want to `echo readfile`. It echos on its own.

Comment: Also note you shouldn't `echo readfile()`, just do `readfile()` by itself, as that already dumps the file to the output buffer. By also calling echo, you're outputting additional infomation, in this case, the return value of readfile() which is the number of bytes output.

Comment: I'm guessing the goal of the regex is to match a filename with an extension, but it does not do that.  The final `[a-z]` is singular, meaning the string should end with a single character.  That's redundant, because the character class before that already specifies one or more of those same characters. `abstract.jpg` matches, but so does `abstract`, and so do `abs` and `a.b`, things which do not look like filenames with extensions. Don't reinvent the wheel, there are surely many questions here with examples of regexs to match filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still a couple of errors in your code:

1. There is no closing parentheses for your initial if block
2. Your preg_match - you're passing a variable $file to it which hasn't been declared. I think you mean to pass $filename. If I am not mistaken, your code is continuing because the preg_match isn't returning false.
3. You're passing $file to create the $filepath variable too, so again, it's just trying to download images/ instead of the full path.

This code works:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['file']))
{
    $filename = $_GET["file"];
    if(preg_match('/^[^.][-a-z0-9_.]+[a-z]$/i', $filename)){
        $filepath = "images/" . $filename;
        if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\""); 
           readfile($filepath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, What to set in `header content type` for mp4 files? I tried `header("Content-Type: video/mp4");`, but no use.

Comment: Have a look around online for MIME types - video/mp4 is a valid MIME type so if it’s not working for you perhaps the source file has a particular codec or something, I’m not sure. Impossible to tell without being able to analyse your source file.